# How to search huge amount of data in Sql Server and paginate them in MVC view?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, pagination, lucene, umbraco7

I have a requirement to create a searching functionality in a web page. The fields to be filtered are `from date` - `to date`, `first money value` - `second money value`, a dropdown with predefined values and a free text.

The database with be `Sql Server` and the CMS is `Umbraco`. I have been searching for the best solution but unfortunately haven't found yet!

- I tried exploring `Elasticsearch`, `Lucene` and other platforms like these, but they do not fit my needs because I have to use `Full Text Search` in Sql Server.
- Entity is not good for this case because it doesn't support `Full Text Search` in Sql Server. There are tricks to do it but primarly it is not the same thing...
- I tried to create a dynamic query depending on fields entered by user but some people say they are not good solutions for big data.
- Another solution came it my mind was creating the query dynamically in application side and then execute it, I'am not sure if this way is good enought?
- Creating big views is not a solution because they can destroy performance as I have been reading in some articles.

Has anybody implemented a good solution for searching huge amount of data where parameters are dynamic(making the query dynamic as well) and the data retrieved needs to be paginated in view ?  I really appreciate if somebody gives me some information on how to make the pagination in `MVC` or `Umbraco`

Furthermore in database might be millions of records and the pagination should be in server side.

If there is no good way from server side to make all the stuff then please provide me with some information how to use `Elasticsearch` or `Lucene` in c#

Comment: for pagination you can use the following query SELECT * FROM <table>
ORDER BY <columns>
OFFSET <EXPR1> ROWS
FETCH NEXT <EXPR2> ROWS ONLY .Instead of loading the entire data you load some 50 rows and do pagination

Comment: This isn't that helpful as he needs to filter data before adding pagination

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Mani but I need the filtering query or the best implementation how to search the data first and then I can use your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'Server Side', I assume you mean SQL Server... If the data you need to query is being written to from Umbraco, I would avoid bypassing Umbraco's data access layer by reading directly from the database as you will have to rewrite the logic to handle publishing & versioning.

Umbraco uses Examine (built on top of Lucene) for providing internal searching and is easily configurable to create your own.

The Examine documentation can be found [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/searching/examine/) and a helpful getting started guide can be found [here](http://24days.in/umbraco/2013/getting-started-with-examine/).